# Styling fixed position in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'd like the top level div with message "This is a test message" pinned to top so it always on top and overlay the following div even (with black background) when i scroll

The "position: fixed" does not seem to make it work

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          top: "0px",
          position: "fixed",
          width: "100%",
          overflow: "hidden"
        }}
      >
        <p>this is a test message</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{
          marginTop: "50px",
          height: "2000px",
          width: "30px",
          background: "black"
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not have to change anything to your code, I just added a few colors and some height: https://react-zda8ht.stackblitz.io

Link to the editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zda8ht

Isn't that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correctly, this is something you need

```
<div id="app">
  The APP
</div>
<div id=message>
  This is a test message
</div>

#app {
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

[the jsfiddle example link](https://jsfiddle.net/xb7cm48s/)

Comment: You don't need to put <body> inside jsfiddle. This doesn't change here anything but top element in OPs question is not <body> but <div>.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.root{
  top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: darkcyan;
    color:white;
}
.inner{
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 1000vh;
    width: 30px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <div class="root">
        <p>this is a test message</p>
      </div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
```